# Planar graph whose every face is a square

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, planar-graphs

> Let $D$ be a planar drawing of a graph such that every face is a triangle. Color the vertices of $D$ in blue, red, or green (without additional conditions). Prove that the number of faces with differently colored edges is even. **Hint** - count in two different ways the pairs $(F,e)$ such that $F$ is a face and $e$ is an edge of it with edges colored in red and blue.

I'm trying to understand the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933055/questions-of-the-form-let-g-be-a-planar-graph-such-that-every-face-is-a) but I don't understand why $\#\text{edges}/2=\#\text{areas}$. For instance, taking 2 squares side by side gives a graph with seven edges and three faces... Can anyone explain the idea? How can I use the fact all faces are square?

Answer (score 1):

Each edge touches two faces and each face touches four edges. These two count the same thing (edge-face contact), so they are equal, and we get $2E = 4F$, or $\frac{E}{2} = F$.

Your example doesn't work because the outside face borders $6$ edges and is not a square.

Comment: But then it seems only a single square would have an outside face which is a square...

Comment: Not necessarily. For example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Cube_graph.png